# mitmproxy reverse proxy - want SSL only on non-standard port

Tags: python, ssl, reverse-proxy, mitmproxy

I want a reverse proxy (using mitmproxy/mitmdump) for an insecure site. I want the proxy to run on a non-standard port (not 443) and to be accessible only via https. This is the closest I've gotten:

`mitmdump -p 2112 --mode reverse:http://localhost:41781 --set block_global=false --certs full.pem`

This works when I access it via https: `https://localhost:2112`. The problem is, it is also accessible via http: `http://localhost:2112`.

How do I disable that and make it only accessible via https?

Comment: Maybe you are using the wrong tool for the job in the first place?  mitmdump is not intended to secure some site but to intercept and possibly modify traffic. Using nginx as reverse proxy might be the more appropriate way to secure a site instead.

Comment: Thanks. I actually have a requirement to modify traffic (I left that part out because it's not relevant to this question) and I have other requirements for this use case that make mitmproxy a good choice, though I have used nginx in other cases.

Answer (score 2):

I have to agree with Steffen. Try to use nginx, f5 or other tools as they are more suitable to be used as a reverse proxy. Although, if you really want to stick with `mitm`, there should be an option called http2 which takes in a boolean to disable http access like this `--no-http2`. So your command should look like something like this

```
mitmdump -p 2112 --mode reverse:http://localhost:41781 --no-http2 --set block_global=false --certs full.pem
```

Comment: Thanks, I'm aware of nginx and other tools, and have used them before. I have special requirements for this use case though and would prefer to use mitmproxy. Unfortunately the `--no-http2` flag did not disable plain http on port 2112. From the name, I'm guessing it just disasbles the HTTP/2.0 protocol?

Comment: Instead of disabling HTTP access, what if you use the redirect feature to "make" https request from all incoming requests?

Answer (score 0):

(Obligatory: Use Apache/nginx/... if you need a production-grade reverse proxy)

Mitmproxy currently always supports both HTTP and HTTPS to simplify setups (we had lots of bug reports because of misconfigurations). If you want to disable HTTP, you could write an addon that detects `flow.request.scheme == "http"` and then either invokes `flow.kill()` or sets `flow.response = mitmproxy.http.HTTPResponse.make(<redirect data here>)`. Lastly, you can also make sure to set HSTS headers in the `response` hook in mitmproxy.